# How to fix a navbar that is expanding (going down) but not collapsing (going back up)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar that has a hamburger toggle when going below a certain screensize. My problem is that the navbar goes down (expands properly) but does not go up again (collapse).

I tried to check other forums and same questions about the same issue but nothing helped. I definitely need some refreshment as I haven't been coding JS for a while.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light white-background">
  <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-wagon-brand" do %>
    <%= image_tag "logo.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#motto"><%= t('about_title') %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services"><%= t('solution_title') %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#why"><%= t('benefits_title') %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#team"><%= t('team_title') %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#partners"><%= t('clients_title') %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact_us"><%= t('contact_us') %></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.enso-value.com/?locale=en"><%= image_tag("english_flag.png", class: "fit-image-flag") %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.enso-value.com/?locale=nl"><%= image_tag("netherlands_flag.png", class: "fit-image-flag") %></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.enso-value.com/?locale=fr"><%= image_tag("french_flag.png", class: "fit-image-flag") %></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I expect the navbar to work properly.

Comment: reference link is https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have the same problem with this navbar (it goes down properly but doesn't come up again when I click on the hamburger menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by commenting in my application.html.erb file the following line of code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thanks all for your help!

How I worked? I started commenting all the lines out to see which impact it had on my navbar and my website and I found out it was the one making it work not properly.